# Trying to use ReportViewer in a console application

Tags: asp.net, .net, reporting-services, report, reportviewer

I'm trying to use ReportViewer in a console application. I'm trying to initialize ReportViewer like this :

```
Dim rvReport As New ReportViewer
```

And I'm getting this exception :

```
"Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Reporting.ControlService..ctor()'."
```

How can I fix this situation? Thanks.

Comment: `Dim rvReport As ReportViewer`

Comment: @Hackerman Thanks. It worked but then rvReport goes as `Nothing` and I'm getting `'System.NullReferenceException'`  when I'm trying to use rvReport. How can I make rvReport as a full report.

Comment: Mmmm, maybe this one `Dim rvReport As ReportViewer = New ReportViewer()`

Comment: @Hackerman It didn't work because it `ReportViewer` doesn't have a constructor as written in the question.

Comment: So, this way it's working `Imports Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim rvReport As ReportViewer = New ReportViewer

        rvReport.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local


    End Sub

End Module`

Comment: Can you post your full code in order to help you out, I was able to create a console app in order to mimic your code

Comment: @Hackerman The problem is my `ReportViewer` is a  very old version. That's why there is no such a constructor.